# RANK, ROW_NUMBER on T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, row-number, dense-rank

I have rows like this in SQL Server 2014:

```
id | fld1
---+-----
1  | 100
2  | 100
3  | 80
4  | 102
5  | 100
6  | 80
7  | 102
```

I would need a *partition* that without changing order would return:

```
  NewFld | id | fld1
  -------+----+------
   1     | 1  | 100
   1     | 2  | 100
   2     | 3  | 80
   3     | 4  | 102
   1     | 5  | 100
   2     | 6  | 80
   3     | 7  | 102
```

`Newfld` should return the same value based on `fld1` without changing ordering given by `id`.

I tried with `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK` but nothing works for me.

View [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5766b/11)

Comment: So, for any particular `fld1` value, if you obtain the `MIN(id)` value for that value, and assign row numbers on those distinct values, you'll get the results you need?

Answer (score 3):

Use `min() over()` in a subquery to establish the ordering values needed for the `dense_rank()`.

```
SELECT id
     , Fld1
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by fld1_idmin) AS Rank
FROM (
       SELECT id
             , fld1
                 , Min (id) over (partition by fld1) fld1_idmin
           FROM yourtable
           ) d
    ORDER BY ID
```

With an index on FLD1 using these window functions needs just a single index scan for this query. See this [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9004/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

you may use this

```
with mytab as 
(
SELECT * 
  ,(SELECT MIN(ID) FROM yourtable sub where sub.fld1 = yourtable.fld1) as ranks
FROM yourtable

 )

 SELECT ID ,fld1 , DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY Ranks)
 FROM mytab
 ORDER BY ID
```

view [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5766b/39)